# Django DRF - update profile using serializer + json

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been bashing my head against the wall on this for about 3 full days now and probably read every thread on SO. Warning = I am not very good with Django REST or indeed Python.

To summarise, each user profile has 11 football players they have initially selected. I now want to update/change these players by POSTing json info.

**views.py**

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    jsondata = dict(request.data)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile, data=jsondata, partial=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializing all the Players
    """
    #user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    GK1 = PlayerSerializer()
    DF1 = PlayerSerializer()
    DF2 = PlayerSerializer()
    DF3 = PlayerSerializer()
    DF4 = PlayerSerializer()
    MF1 = PlayerSerializer()
    MF2 = PlayerSerializer()
    MF3 = PlayerSerializer()
    MF4 = PlayerSerializer()
    FW1 = PlayerSerializer()
    FW2 = PlayerSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = ( "GK1", "DF1", "DF2", "DF3", "DF4", "MF1", "MF2", "MF3", "MF4", "MF5", "FW1", "FW2",)
```

Right now as a test I am trying to update simply GK1. I know that I am getting correct json data via POST. I also know the instance data is the original data. However it just will not save/update!!! I have overridden the update method as a test:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        setattr(instance, "GK1.id", validated_data['GK1']['id'])
        instance.save()
        return instance

### set the id of GK1 to the id that arrives via POST
### GK1.id gives me '1008' - a Player object
### validated_data['GK1']['id'] gives me '1025' - id of another player
```

Nothing happens - the id does not change in the DB :(

Here's my main question -

validated_data is an OrderedDict (fine)

instance is a User Profile object.

How do I squeeze the OrderedDict data into the Profile object? Can I do this simply by referencing the Primary Foreign Key? I.e. id?

I've very sorry about how vague this is and perhaps the lack of code. But the DRF tutorial is not clear imho. Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT - json data / validated_data added to comments**

**EDIT2 - I have a working solution**
I've changed the update method to do the following for each player:
instance.GK1 = PlayerID.objects.get(id=validated_data['GK1'].pop('id'))

Or in other words, the instance was looking for Player OBJECTS (and not a string representation of the id). Therefore I popped out the id and filtered (or .get) by the id of the object.

Thanks for reading, I have a massive weight off my shoulders...

Comment: Could you post the json file too

Comment: You don't want jsondata = dict(request.data). Because request.data is dict.

Comment: print(validated_data) --- https://pastebin.com/064DfwjY

Comment: @a_k_v perhaps I'm misunderstanding but the serializer.is_valid() will only give me an ordered dict to work with in the serializer.

Comment: Yes thats right.

Comment: From your question i assume you are using a nested json structure. In that case you may need to override update method in your serializer and need to store each entry individually.

Comment: Yep, my issue is I cannot seem to update any field. I have the new (validated) data. I know what part of the profile object I want to update. I just can't seem to do it with setattr(instance, "GK1.id", validated_data['GK1']['id']) alone. Perhaps I need to update every field of the object instead of just the primary key (id)....

Comment: When you query players then it may not in the same order as it saved.

Comment: I dont know what is exactly PlayerSerializer or models are!

Comment: Not too worried about order as the front end (if required) will re-sort things for me. Plus just trying to get the basics sorted in this early iteration -_-

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the update method to do the following for each player:

`instance.GK1 = PlayerID.objects.get(id=validated_data['GK1'].pop('id'))`

Or in other words, the instance was looking for Player OBJECTS (and not a string representation of the id). Therefore I popped out the id and filtered (or .get) by the id of the object.

Thanks for reading, I have a massive weight off my shoulders...